# Ubuntu hangs at boot after upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, 20.10, 21.04

I've been using Ubunth 20.04 for a few months. Fresh install.

I decided to update to 20.10 and it appeared to go smoothly. However, after I rebooted all I could see was this:

```
/dev/sda5: clean, 764403/30498816 files, 30197898/121964800 blocks
```

Not sure what happened, but when I press the power button, it instantly starts shutting down, including showing the graphical splash screen.

At startup, I do see my graphical boot splash. When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>ESC</kbd>, I can see the startup terminal with a few dependency errors...

[image: dependency errors]

I'm not entirely sure what to do next... keys do nothing, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> briefly shows the startup terminal, then shows a blank screen with a text cursor. I still can't do anything.

What should I do next?

EDIT 1: I have access to the rescue mode, but I don't have network access. If I could enable networking, I should be able to update some packages.

EDIT 2: I was able to boot to rescue mode with networking and install the package it was complaining about. However, when booting normally, my laptop hangs on this...

[image: new hanging spot]

EDIT 3: I was able to upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04, which I originally wanted to do anyways. I'm now back at the beginning with the same message I started with, just with different numbers.

Comment: According to this question, SSSD can cause boot to fail. Disabling it supposedly solves it, but it did not in ny case. I'm still hanging at the second screenshot, however, with no SSSD-related errors. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289954/having-sssd-problems-at-boot-since-upgrading-to-20-10

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Edit:
this should solve your network problems

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: I can only access rescue/emergency mode, but I cant figure out how to enable networking. Running `apt update` did say I could upgrade a package, but I couldn't since I didn't have a network connection.

Comment: Update! I have network access and I installed the package it was asking for. It still doesn't boot correctly. I went back and ran each command again, and on the last one, it hangs and terminates with `exit status 1.`

Answer (score 1):

To enable networking in emergency mode, try to use:

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

Verify then with `ifconfig` that your connection is up. There are other commands like `ifup` or `nmcli` that you might try if the above doesn't work. See [systemd-networkd - No networking in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930965/systemd-networkd-no-networking-in-recovery-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the graphics drivers were somehow uninstalled. Reinstalling them did the trick.